# Excel string variables not working in range

Tags: excel, vba

I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me to the right direction. I'm trying to do a simple macro to hide selected set of rows. I could combine Set 1 and 2 in the variables, but they are two different sets of information and I want them separated so it is easier to maintain as the code grows.

I'm wondering if there are ways to see how range resolves my variables.

This code works

```
Const Set1 As String = "1:2,4:5"
Const Set2 As String = "7:8,11:12"

Sub test()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Set1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Set2).EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

```
Sub test2()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("1:2,4:5,7:8,11:12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

But not this

```
Const Set1 As String = "1:2,4:5"
Const Set2 As String = "7:8,11:12"


Sub test()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Set1, Set2).EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with the first `test` approach?  The last one doesn't work because passing two arguments to Range() implies they are the top-left and bottom-right corners of a larger range.

Comment: Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Set1 & "," & Set2).EntireRow.Hidden = True

Comment: @TimWilliams nothing's wrong with the first approach, I want them in single lines if possible, just like how it worked without the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ampersand (&) to concatenate two or more variable with string. This worked for me:

```
Sub test()
    
Const Set1 As String = "1:2,4:5"
Const Set2 As String = "7:8,11:12"
        
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Set1 & "," & Set2).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Multiple Ranges

You could study the short article [Application.Union method (Excel) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union). Using this method you could write something like the following:

```
Sub testUnion()
    
    Const Set1 As String = "1:2,4:5"
    Const Set2 As String = "7:8,11:12"
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Union(ws.Range(Set1), ws.Range(Set2))
    rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    
End Sub
```